# Centos 6.5 not able to login with public key and login is sloooooow

Tags: ssh, centos, public-key-authentication

I set up a new system with CentOS 6.5. I copied my public key key with:

```
ssh-copy-id root@192.168.1.202
```

It took 15+ seconds for the password prompt to show, but then it copied.

However `ssh` to root@192.168.1.202 still asks for the password. The permissions on the directory `.ssh` are `700` and on the file `.ssh/authorized_keys` `600` (owner & group) `root`. This is the same as on a server running Debian where public key login is working.

There is no obvious thing in the `sshd_config` that I could see needs to be changed.

How can I automate public key login? If that is fixed does that help speed up the login?

Comment: Like Anthon said in his answer, the two are actually unrelated problems. Using '-v' option with 'ssh' while logging in will throw some extra light to see what is happening.

Comment: I tried -v but did not see a problem, but it is solved now thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are actually unrelated problems. If the permissions of the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file are correct run:

```
restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh
```

and you should be able to login with your private-public key pair.

To solve the slow login issue you can disable the following entries in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
```

and restart with `service sshd restart`